# Make new onclick listeners not overwrite previous ones

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, textview

I want certain buttons to set text on certain textviews when clicked depending on their position in the array, I want the first four cases to make the first textview say "yeah", and the second four to make the second textview say "no".  The first four cases worked until I added the second four, at which time all 8 of the buttons i'd created listeners for made the second textview say "no".

So it seems like the most recent listener is replacing all previous ones

```
    public void applyClick(Button[] button, final TextView[] texty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            switch(i) {
                case 0:case 1:case 2:case 3: {
                    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            texty[0].setText("yeah");
                        }
                    });
                }
                case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7: {
                    button[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            texty[1].setText("no");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put a break after each of the 2 cases.